# ill_typed_data and invalid_contract_notation smart contract deployment error

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract on the testnet. I have made sure it is well typed. But I faced the error message below when trying to deploy on both bablynonnet and carthagenet. Could someone guide me on where did it go wrong?

```
Status: failed

Error: proto.006-PsCARTHA.michelson_v1.ill_typed_data
Error: proto.006-PsCARTHA.contract.invalid_contract_notation
```

smartpy code: https://pastebin.com/4Hn6VThX

Michelson code generated by smartpy: https://pastebin.com/G6turJ8F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using invalid addresses.

Comment: Thanks! I was using the wrong address indeed, successfully originated now. Switched to `sp.test_account` and all is good. Was amused that the test made a difference, even though the michelson code was the same for both.

Comment: The michelson must be different. Please share the originated contract address ?

Comment: I can confirm that the only change required was in the test. How can a change in the smartpy test affects the deployment of the Smart Contract?

Comment: General answer is that origination is done from contracts defined in tests. More specific one is that initial storage is important as well and I expect that this is what changed.